# Can we generate HPD regions from MCMC draws using convex hulls?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, convex, highest-density-region

I thought of a procedure to generate high probability density regions with probability $1-\alpha$ from $n$ MCMC draws:

1. Find the $\lfloor(1-\alpha)\cdot n\rfloor$ draws with the largest probability density;
2. Take the confidence hull of these draws as an approximate HPD region.

Is this procedure correct? I believe it only works when the distribution is convex (or maybe log-convex, I'm not sure). I think this is a more flexible approach than using Mahalanobis distance, since the resulting region is convex but not ellipsoidal, and requires less tuning than kernel density based methods.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How many dimensions are we talking here? :)

Comment: @usεr11852 I was thinking 2-3 dimensions. Would it fail in high dimensions? KDE would fail there too due to the curse of dimensionality, right?

Comment: Yes, my worry was this would be used in some with 10+ dimensions where I would expect it to down-right fail.